# understanding Azure Sql Databse Billed VCores

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database, azure, cpu

trying to migrate from sql server on-prem to azure sql database and i cant understand **Duration** and **CPU Used** and **Memory Used** of Billed vCores
[image: Billed vCores]

Answer (score 0):

[Azure SQL Database Serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview) has auto-pause, and you don't pay for VCores while your database is paused.

The Duration in the price calculator is your estimate of how long your database will be active each month.  CPU Used is your estimate of how many cores, on average, you need for the Duration.  Memory used is your estimate of how much memory your workload needs.

You are charged per VCore/hour, and each VCore comes with a fixed amount of Memory.  You may need to increase your VCores to get your required memory.